# AutoClear input field after submit with Js

Tags: javascript, input, forms

Would like your help resolving this piece of code.
Trying to clear inputs after submit but not able to.
Can someone give me a hint??
Thank you so much.

```
        <script>
        var list = document;
        function process(idTable)
        {   
            var newRow = list.createElement('tr');
            newRow.insertCell(0).innerHTML = list.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
            newRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = list.getElementsByName('surname')[0].value;
            newRow.insertCell(2).innerHTML = list.getElementsByName('email')[0].value;
            list.getElementById(idTable).appendChild(newRow);
            return false;

            list.getElemntsByName('form')[0].value="";
        }
    </script>


<section>
    <form name="form" method="post" id="myForm" onsubmit=" return process('myTable')" >  
        <p> <label>Name:</label>    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder = "Your first name" required> </p>
        <p> <label>Surname:</label> <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder = "Your last name" required> </p>
        <p> <label>Email:</label>   <input type="e-mail" name="email" placeholder = "xpto@example.com" required> </p>
        <p> <input type="submit" value="Add"> <input type="reset"  value="Reset"> </p>      
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Explain why you need to clear the fields and show us the (submit?) code you made so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points:

1. You exited the function before assign value to the form
2. Better use `list.getElemntsByName('form')[0].reset()`;

So your code will be like this:

```
 <script>
    var list = document;
    function process(idTable)
    {   
        var newRow = list.createElement('tr');
        newRow.insertCell(0).innerHTML = list.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
        newRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = list.getElementsByName('surname')[0].value;
        newRow.insertCell(2).innerHTML = list.getElementsByName('email')[0].value;
        list.getElementById(idTable).appendChild(newRow);


        list.getElemntsByName('form')[0].reset();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot SouXin. It worked immediately! Starting learning Java for almost 3 weeks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use button tag for your 'submit' and 'reset', then in that use clientclick event, have reset function that clears the input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use $('#id of input element ').val(' ')  inside process function . Also write this code above return false statement

Comment: He's using pure JS